# Docker and nodemcu-build. Excited but unable to run it

Tags: windows, docker, nodemcu

I tried to install docker image today to build my firmware for esp6288 with http server and it seems that I failed miserably.

Install docker toolbox.

Run "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh" aka "Docker Quickstart Terminal" shortcut

```
See:

                    ##         .
              ## ## ##        ==
           ## ## ## ## ##    ===
       /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
       \______ o           __/
         \    \         __/
          \____\_______/
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

Start interactive shell

Jaroslaw@lpatop MINGW64 ~
$
```

Run "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\kitematic\Kitematic.exe" aka Kitematic (Alpha)

Search nodemcu-build by marcelstoer
Click Create...
After download, run.
See container logs:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
cp: cannot stat 'tools/esp-open-sdk.tar.gz': No such file or directory
```

Proceed according to https://hub.docker.com/r/marcelstoer/nodemcu-build/:

Open cmd:
Go to C:\Users\Jaroslaw (cmd already opens up in that dir)
Run git clone https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware.git
See, folder is there.
Go in to that folder.
Run:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v //c/Users/Jaroslaw/nodemcu-firmware:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build
```

See output:

```
docker: An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.23/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified..
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Can you tell me what should I do to make this work? I'm very excited to start building my universal IoT unit for my home purposes with http server onboard.

Answer (score 1):

The default NodeMCU firmware can be used to create an HTTP server. You don't need to build the firmware from source again to do that.

1. Download precompiled NodeMCU firmware from [here](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/releases/tag/0.9.6-dev_20150704). (Note that it's not the latest version! Latest no longer ships with precompiled binaries since there are lots of configurations to choose from. Once you get started, it is recommended to build the latest firmware as mentioned in bold below since this old version is reported to be buggy.)
2. Download ESPFlasher from [here](http://www.xess.com/blog/esp8266-reflash/) and flash the firmware onto the chip. (This is the only flasher that worked for mee).
3. Just flash the firmware onto the chip and download [ESPlorer IDE](http://esp8266.ru/esplorer/). The IDE allows you to write Lua scripts onto the device, which can also be used to create an HTTP server.
4. See [this page](http://www.instructables.com/id/ESP8266-Web-Server-Without-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS) for an example of a web server emulated on ESP8266. This example works out of the box if you are using the precompiled firmware from (1). If you are building your own firmware from the latest source, it is recommended to use [these](https://github.com/marcoskirsch/nodemcu-httpserver) scripts which are maintained.

Hope this helps.

#### To build your own firmware, simply do this:

If you ever feel like compiling your own firmware from the latest source, you can always head over to http://nodemcu-build.com and compile a custom firmware online, and get it emailed to you.

Comment: Those a valid points but need some corrections. Do NOT use any of the very old pre-built 0.9.x binaries. They're no longer maintained and contain lots of bugs. As for an HTTP server I suggest you use https://github.com/marcoskirsch/nodemcu-httpserver. It seems to be the only one that's more or less maintained. It's very easy to burn yourself implementing a more-than-Hello-World server.